# Trying to show a jqModal dialog on $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jqmodal

I'm adapting a jqModal script to launch in an onLoad fashion using the `$(document).ready` method, but I'm getting something wrong somewhere. I'm new to stackoverflow, and I smell brains all over this place. (Wish I was one of them.) The full page code (relatively short) can be seen by viewing the source of this URL:
http://www.caycecookbook.com/pop_ups/jqm_onDocReady/jqm_docReady.html

The short end of the code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#rename').jqm();
    });
</script> 
<!-- POP-UP DIV -->
<DIV class="jqmWindow" id="rename" style="padding:18px 0px 12px 0px;">
    <TABLE align="center" width="500" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#7777777">
        <TR><TD align="center"><P style="margin: 12px 12px 12px 12px;">
<img src="images/hey_there.jpg" width="504" height="360"  border="0"></p></td></tr>
        <TR><TD align="center" valign="middle">
            <P style="margin:6px 0px 0px 0px;">
                <a href="#" class="jqmClose" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff;; 
font-family: arial, helvetica, verdana, sans-serif; font-size:12px; 
font-weight:bold;">Close</a>
            </p>
        </td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Well, it won't come up... the code's broken somewhere and I can't find it...

Comment: This is perhaps a side-issue, but it's a little strange that you've included the contents of jqModal.js and jqModal.css in your page rather than linking to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never call `jqmShow` to show the dialog. You only initialize its parameters with `jqm`.

Ref: http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/#how

**Update**

Here is the requested code example:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#rename').jqm();
        $('#rename').jqmShow(); // This is the line you need to add.
    });
</script>
```

Comment: If you want the dialog to show immediately, you should call `jqmShow` after you call `jqm`. According to the jqModal documentation, `jqmShow` should be called to manually trigger a dialog.

Comment: What would that look like—the code—if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: Gordo... your my hero, man... if you ever wanted to be a hero, you jus made it. Thank you for taking the time for an obvious neophyte. I'll pay it forward somehow.